# Calculate the distance in $C[0,1]$ from the function $x(t) = t^2$ to the linear hull of the functions $y(t) = t$ and $z(t) = \sin t.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

The following question is taken from '[Banach space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781441975140)', Chapter $1,$ question $1.8.$

> **Question:** Calculate the distance in $C[0,1]$ from the function $x(t) = t^2$ to the linear hull of the functions $y(t) = t$ and $z(t) = \sin t.$

So we are asked to calculate 
$$\inf_{a,b\in\mathbb{R}} \max_{t\in[0,1]}|t^2-at-b\sin(t)|.$$
Fix $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and denote 
$$f(t) = t^2-at-b\sin(t).$$
By differentiation, we obtain 
$$f'(t) = 2t-a-b\cos(t),$$
To find stationary point, we set 
$$f'(t) = 2t - a-b\cos(t)=0,$$
which implies that 
$$2t-a=b\cos(t).$$
But I have trouble solving the equation above.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the values at the endpoints $0$, $1$ into account as well. Anyway, I think this problem can only be solved numerically. By playing around with Mathematica I obtained the following approximation which shows that the distance in question is $\leq 0.026$.

[image]

Comment: You got those constants in such a way that the approximation is $+$, $-$, $+$, with about equal deviation. So you can state that the best approximation cannot be smaller than the smaller of these deviations, right? Otherwise you would get a function of form $p t + q \sin t$ with $3$ zeroes ( including $t=0$), so the derivative would have $2$, not possible. I just wonder how you got these nice values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I started with $\sin t\approx{4\over\pi^2} t(\pi-t)$ and tuned the constants until I obtained a satisfying picture.

Comment: So can you make those local max deviations all equal to any degree of precision? If you can then you get the best approximation. It might work fine with Mathematica, which I do not have at the moment.  Hm, maybe use the command Manipulate with a plot...I think you got the value very close